# how to handle XML file in RapidMiner?

Tags: xml, visualization, data-visualization, rapidminer, gate

I have obtained XML file from Gate after doing emotion analysis and I need to handle it in Rapidminer in order to visualize it.Do you have suggestions how to do this? does rapidminer accept XML files?

Answer (score 0):

RapidMiner offers a *Read XML* operator with which you can load a XML file as an ExampleSet (RapidMiner's standard data format). Just search for XML in the operator list or via the global search field (upper right corner).
Specifying the exact file structure might be a bit tricky, if the file is very nested.

Feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com).

[image]